# Ninja build is failing intermittently

Tags: rpm, dpdk, ninja, meson-build, dpdk-pmd

I am building DPDK 21.11.1. I have installed both ninja and meson packages along with all required tools. My meson build is successful. It generates the ninja.build file. My meson version in .49.2.
While running the ninja command build is failing at

.**./../BUILDROOT/external/dpdk/Linux/RPM/root-dpdk/.ninja_log**
lib/76b5a35@@rte_vhost@sta/vhost_vhost_crypto.c.o       a4371e2d46dc69fc
lib/76b5a35@@rte_pipeline@sta/pipeline_rte_table_action.c.o     6110779d602aab2f

After that, it's existing without giving any error. There are a lot of files to compile/build after this entry in ninja.build file. I tried upgrading the meson version to meson-0.61.5 but no luck.
**gcc version is **gcc (GCC) 10.2.1 20210130 (Red Hat 10.2.1-11)**

I am using following commands in spec file.
meson  -Dprefix=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_prefix} --buildtype=debug   %{buildroot}
cd %{buildroot}
ninja

where buildroot is my build dir. I tried using the -v option of the ninja as well but it's not showing any error.  Could you please suggest how can I  fix this issue?

Comment: from your current explanation are you trying to say `follwoed the recommended steps as DPDK, but noticed 2 lines reporting something in vhost_cryto,c and pipeline_rte_table_action.c. But the build is reported as successful. Is there something wrong?`. If this is the real question update the error content in `BUILDROOT/external/dpdk/Linux/RPM/root-dpdk/.ninja_log`

Comment: @VipinVarghese I mean build.ninja file has many entries to be built by ninja. For example  grep -nw "build" build.ninja | wc -l  shows  2855 build commands. .ninja_log gives the list of files that are built successfully. It does not give any other information. But for some reason   its stopping at lib/76b5a35@@rte_pipeline@sta/pipeline_rte_table_action.c.o 6110779d602aab2f and not building further entries in the file. I am not getting any other errors also so it's a bit difficult to identify what is causing it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I am not still clear with the issue. May I live debug will help to diagnose the same

Comment: @VipinVarghese I need to build dpdk with following option CONFIG_RTE_MACHINE="native",CONFIG_RTE_ARCH="x86_64",CONFIG_RTE_ARCH_X86_64=y,CONFIG_RTE_ARCH_X86=y,CONFIG_RTE_ARCH_64=y,CONFIG_RTE_TOOLCHAIN="gcc", CONFIG_RTE_TOOLCHAIN_GCC=y Do you know meson equivalent of these config. I am not able to get those in meson -h option.

Comment: please update the request (as the question and explanation) with DPDK version. I will try and update as answer

Comment: @VipinVarghese Seems like I got the issue. rpmbuild is failing with error : Exception: elftools module not found. I have installed it using the command pip3 install pyelftools. After searching I found that (https://www.spinics.net/lists/centos-devel/msg21516.html) path of elftool is located under /usr/local/lib/site-packages and meson is using python /usr/bin/python3(with /usr/lib/site-packages). I tried creating symbolic links using a spec file but even after that also it's not working.

Comment: good to hear the prime cause of error is identified. Like said the current logs that you had  shared did not have much information and it is assumed you had followed and installed all dependencies. But it was not so,

Comment: @VipinVarghese Dependencies were installed earlier also. The only thing that was built was not reporting the error. After using the verbose option I got the issue. Seems like we cannot use pip3 packages with rpms. RPMs build ignores it. pyelftools tool is installed but it is not getting picked while building RPMs. Due to that ninja build is failing.

Comment: i am bot of a loss here, at first you mention you see some build issue via ninja `vhost_vhost_crypto. and ip_pipeline`. Assuming you will be using this, we decided to explore. Then in the latest comments you mention you got the cause of error and installed `pyelftools`. So expectation is with `ninja clean; ninja -v` the error is no more. But now you are claiming error is there because the dependencies was installed before but ninja did not report. Very odd and I am finding it difficult to connect the dots. I had extended for a quick live debug, but I will leave it to you

Comment: @VipinVarghese I will break down this in steps 1) Initially I reported that my ninja build was failing and ninja log was reporting errors related to vhost_vhost_crypto.c.o 2) we have our own build system to build the rpm package. Initially, I was using the make install command which interns will use spec file and start building. This time build was stopped at above mention point (vhost_vhost_crypto.c.o) without reporting any error. 3)  The I used make install verbose command and it reported issues related to pyelftools.

Comment: @VipinVarghese   At that point, I found out that pip install packages do not work with rpm build as I mentioned in the above comment (spinics.net/lists/centos-devel/msg21516.html). I this point I am looking into pyelftools issue. Thanks for helping hand but since this is related to work. I cannot have  debug session. I am trying to create a symbolic link to /usr/local/lib  from /usr/lib/ path so that elftool can be picked by the build.

Comment: very intersting for 2 points `1. CONFIG_RTE_MACHINE="native"Do you know meson equivalent of this config.  and 2. since this is related to work I cannot have debug session`. issue reported from your end is about DPDK build ninja issue and options. `I really doubt it has anything related to work.` . I rest my case, best wishes